# Array overwritten (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on a SPA that will let us search through movie titles and scenarists names (an studies project). Well, I got stuck on a weird problem. Unfortunately when i try to connect the 2 tables (scenarists and movies) into one (so i can get many-many connections) The new array that gets create is always overwritten with the last created object. I can't find the problem, I'll be glad if someone can help. The problem is somewhere between the push methond and the respond.json(movie).

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var port = +process.argv[2];

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var movieID = 11; //first free movie's id
var scenaristID = 15; // first free scenarist's id
var scenarists = [ { id: 1, name: "Glenn Ficarra"},
              { id: 2, name: "John Requa"},
              { id: 3, name: "Jakub Kos"},
              { id: 4, name: "David Kos"},
              { id: 5, name: "Jonathan Nolan"},
              { id: 6, name: "Christopher Nolan"},
              { id: 7, name: "Jeb Stuart"},
              { id: 8, name: "Steven E. de Souza"},
              { id: 9, name: "Doug Richardson"},
              { id: 10, name: "Jason Hall"},
              { id: 11, name: "Noah Oppenheim"},
              { id: 12, name: "T.S Nowlin"},
              { id: 13, name: "Luc Besson"},
              { id: 14, name: "Michael Allin"}];

var movies = [ { id: 1, title: "Focus", scenarist1: 1, scenarist2: 2},
          { id: 2, title: "Test Drive", scenarist1: 3, scenarist2: 4},
          { id: 3, title: "Interstellar", scenarist1: 5, scenarist2: 6},
          { id: 4, title: "Die Hard", scenarist1: 7, scenarist2: 8},
          { id: 5, title: "Die Hard 2", scenarist1: 8, scenarist2: 9},
          { id: 6, title: "The Dark Knight Rises", scenarist1: 5, scenarist2: 6},
          { id: 7, title: "American Sniper", scenarist1: 10, scenarist2: -1},
          { id: 8, title: "The Maze Runner", scenarist1: 11, scenarist2: 12},
          { id: 9, title: "Taxi", scenarist1: 13, scenarist2: -1},
          { id: 10, title: "Enter The Dragon", scenarist1: 14, scenarist2: -1}];

movieCollection = new Array();

//GET - pobranie kolekcji
app.get('/movies', function (request, respond) {
    var i, scen1, scen2, scenarists, movie, movie2;
    console.log('reading movies');
    movie = { title: undefined,
             scenarist1: undefined,
             scenarist2: undefined,
             id: undefined
            };

    for (i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
        scen1 = movies[i].scenarist1;
        scen2 = movies[i].scenarist2;
        scenarists = connectScenarist(scen1, scen2);
        console.log('scenarists ' + i + ' = ' + scenarists.scenarist1 + ', ' + scenarists.scenarist2);
        movie.scenarist1 = scenarists.scenarist1;
        movie.scenarist2 = scenarists.scenarist2;
        movie.id = movies[i].id;
        movie.title = movies[i].title;
        movieCollection.push(movie);
        //console.log(movieCollection[i].scenarist1);
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(movieCollection));
    }
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(movieCollection));
    console.log(movieCollection[2].scenarist1);
    respond.json(movieCollection);
});

function connectScenarist(sce1, sce2) {
    var i, counter, allScenarists;
    counter = 0;
    allScenarists = {
        scenarist1: undefined,
        scenarist2: undefined
    };
    if (sce1 === -1) {
        allScenarists.scenarist1 = "-";
        counter++;
    }
    if (sce2 === -1) {
        allScenarists.scenarist2 = "-";
        counter++;
    }
    if (counter < 2) {
        for (i = 0; i < scenarists.length; i++) {
            if (sce1 === scenarists[i].id) {
                allScenarists.scenarist1 = scenarists[i].name;
                counter++;
            }
            if (sce2 === scenarists[i].id) {
                allScenarists.scenarist2 = scenarists[i].name;
                counter++;
            }
            if (counter === 2) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //console.log('Saving movie: ' + JSON.stringify(allScenarists));
    return allScenarists;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there's only a single `movie` object in your function. Objects don't get copied on assignment or on call in JavaScript. Create a new one on every iteration by putting the literal in the body of your loop!

Also, there is a single `movieCollection` array in your app that is shared by all requests. Not exactly what you want, getting the results of other users.

```
var movieCollection = [];
for (var i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
    var m = movies[i],
        scenarists = connectScenarist(m.scenarist1, m.scenarist2);
    movieCollection.push({
        title: m.title,
        scenarist1: scenarists.scenarist1,
        scenarist2: scenarists.scenarist2,
        id: m.id
    });
    console.log(movieCollection[i]);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(movieCollection));
```

Comment: Wow, i didn't know that i can't use the same object for a temporary use. Thanks for the advise! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the jQuery's extend

Try this:

```
var object = $.extend({}, object1, object2);
```